# Code: 159. DB::Exception: Timeout exceeded: elapsed 5.0 seconds, maximum: 3. (TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED) (version 22.10.2.11 (official build))

Tags: java, clickhouse

I use a JAVA program to connect to Clickhouse through JDBC, and an error will be reported after more than three seconds:

> Code: 159. DB::Exception: Timeout exceeded: elapsed 5.060592159 seconds, maximum: 3. (TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED) (version 22.10.2.11 (official build))，

But I don't have this problem through third-party connection tools(Such as IntelliJ IDEA), I changed `max_execution_time value=800` which didn't solve this problem, added to the JDBC connection URL socket_timeout .

I changed the configuration file `max_execution_time = 800`

Comment: Are you sure your max_execution_time was applied properly?

what show `clickhouse-client -q "SELECT * FROM system.settings WHERE changed"`?

Answer (score 0):

Set Socket Timeout in Clickhouse properties:

for package `ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDataSource`

```
ClickHouseProperties properties = new ClickHouseProperties();
properties.setSocketTimeout(60000);

ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url, properties);
```

for package `com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDataSource`

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("socket_timeout", 60000);
ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other responders suggested, would suggest please providing a little more data. A long query could take a while to provide results, and therefore could timeout, but the default timeouts in ClickHouse server are the following:

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings

```
connect_timeout: 10s
receive_timeout: 300s
send_timeout: 300s
```

3 seconds seems very short, and suggests some other problem to me. Providing the query here in StackOverflow, as well as testing with clickhouse-client, both seem like good next steps.

Also, there is an official ClickHouse JDBC driver if you're not using that - I can't exactly tell from your post: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("socket_timeout", 60000);
ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url, properties);
```

Worked for me when i used com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDataSource;

Answer (score 0):

The most critical line code configuration is

```
properties.setSocketTimeout(60000);
```